# Render a environment variable in jinja template

Tags: python, jinja2

I am new to Jinja templates and hence the question.
Say I have a string in python:

```py
 a="{{environment_variable.person1}} says hello to {{environment_variable.person2}}}"
```

I have to replace this with the environment variables namely **person1** and **person2**. To do that, in my code that I wrote was something like this:

```py
 def parse_variable():
     template= Template(a,trim_blocks=True,lstrip_blocks=True)
     dict={'environment_variable.person1':'P','environment_variable.person2':'Q'}
     template.render(dict)
```

This assumes that I am calling a function and does not render the template. Is there a better way to do the same?

Comment: Is this a Django web application?  Also, don't use `dict` or any of the core data types (int, list, str, etc) or any built-in function names (min, max, len) as variable names.  Python doesn't prevent it as they aren't true reserved keywords, but after doing so you can no longer access the `dict()` or other function later in the code because it is superceded by the `dict` variable.

Comment: no tis is not django web application

Comment: The code `{{environment_variable.person1}}` wants to get the attribute `person1` from the object `environment_variable`. Either change the template or insert a class instance that has `person1` and `person2`.